# Hibernate auto Id generation with initial value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, generator

Is it possible in Spring Hibernate (connected to a MySQL database) to use an auto id generator
without a dedicated sequence table like

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
```

but specify an initial Value for id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-id):

> AUTO: selects IDENTITY, SEQUENCE or TABLE depending upon the
>   capabilities of the underlying database.

So the initial value is the default initial value of the chosen generator. For example in case of the `IDENTITY` generator, it is the `auto_increment_value` of the primary key column of the table.

Comment: So is it possible then to set the auto_increment_value on database creation to a specific value using Annotations?

Comment: No. You can set it in your database though. Or you can set it while creating your database in the SQL script.

Comment: Can I make Hibernate run some custom code, when it creates the DB? I don't want to create the DB with Hibernate and then manually change something on the DB...

Comment: Stupid question ;) I got it!